# Trying to add Integers in HashMap but not working

Tags: java, hashmap

I am new to `HashMaps` and I was helped on understanding how to add and print integers in the map. HOWEVER, instead of getting what I want I get something weird and different that I'm not sure how to fix.

**OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!
Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 10050
```

As you may notice, the total points is just a combination of the scores. This is what I want

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!
Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!
Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 150
```

Also another problem you might notice in my output is `line 3` repeating the first rescue in `line 2` but first I want to focus on the first problem.

Here is my code

**GameDriver.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         Hero N = new Cop();
         String s;
         File f = new File (args[0]);
         Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
         while (input.hasNext()) {
                s = input.next();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
                                               System.out.println(N.getHeroName());
                                             }

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) {
                                               String cn = input.next();
                                               int pts = input.nextInt();
                                               N.newMap.put(cn, pts);
                                               System.out.println(N.rescue());

                                             }

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("v")) {
                                               System.out.println(N.view());
                                             }
         }

  }
}
```

The summation happens in this class

**Hero.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Hero extends Character
{
   private String heroname1;
   public Hero() {
          heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; //the default player name
   }
   HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   public Hero(String newhero) {
          if (newhero.length() > 0) {
               heroname1 = newhero;
          } else { heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; } //defaulted as protagonist
   }

   public String getHeroName() {
          return heroname1; //return the name
   }

   public String rescue() { //class to rescue people or things
          String out = "".toString();
          for(String _key : newMap.keySet()) {
              out += heroname1 + " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key) +!
          }
          return out;
   }

   public String toString() { //print
          return heroname1;

   }
   public String view() {
          Set<String> names = newMap.keySet();
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Characters rescued: ");
          int i = 0;
          for (String name : names) {
              if (i == 0) {
                  sb.append(name);
                  i++;
              } else {
                  sb.append(", ");
                  sb.append(name);
              }
          }

          String printNames = sb.toString();
          Collection<Integer> points = newMap.values();
          StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder("Total points: ");
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer value : points) {
               sum += value;
               sp.append(value);
          }
          String printPoints = sp.toString();
          return printNames + " " + printPoints ;
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please ask for any clarification! **THANKS!!**

Comment: Don't edit your question to change the question after people have solved the problem you asked about. Ask a new question separately and leave the old one as it was.

Comment: Ok. I figured that would be frowned upon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your just appending the text here:

```
StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder("Total points: ");
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer value : points) {
               sum += value;
               sp.append(value);//you're wrong here.
          }
```

You should append after summation of variable sum.

```
StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder("Total points: ");
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer value : points) {
               sum += value;
          }
 sp.append(sum);
```

Also the append value should be 'sum' not 'value';

Comment: Ah perfect thank you. Can I hassle you a tad more and look at my code and tell me why in my output it repeats the first rescue? It's ok if you don't I just can't figure that one out either